Two output files share the same path but have different contents: three_examples_jsm_controls_orbitControls__js.js
enter image description here
i m use vite + vue3 + threejs to import some model, my console alert error like picture. it seems that not effect my code
i want clear this error
7:30:54 PM [vite] error while updating dependencies:
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
error: Two output files share the same path but have different contents: node_modules/.vite/deps_temp_f512f20b/three_examples_jsm_controls_orbitControls__js.js
    at failureErrorWithLog (/Users/wangzhongqing/Desktop/Mine/my-threejs-import/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.21.5/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1472:15)
    at /Users/wangzhongqing/Desktop/Mine/my-threejs-import/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.21.5/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:945:25
    at /Users/wangzhongqing/Desktop/Mine/my-threejs-import/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.21.5/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1353:9
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)



I don't exactly know what is happening, but you surely have dependency issues. Vite isn't able to work around the orbitcontrols. Try removing the node_modules folder and running npm install again. If that doesn't work, share the error (if it changed) and show us how you imported the Orbitcontrols.js file.
